# MyApp is misconfigured for Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App is misconfigured for Facebook login : Android Facebook integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)

I connect and post something on MyApp using Facebook SDK. Everything's ok until I install Facebook app then login to it. After that, I login MyApp again... Bump! An error happens:

Facebook dialog shows error: "MyApp is misconfigured for Facebook login. Press Ok to go back to the application without connecting it to Facebook".

When I signout Facebook app then login MyApp, it still shows the above error. What a strange problem! It's like a bug.

I guess Single Sign On makes MyApp open FacebookApp's dialog. It make something more security but why does it generates the above error once I logged in? I think they use the same session. How to make them to act independently?

I tried to set Android KeyHash and enable Single Sign On but nothing changes. OK, I disable all of them and try again, nothing changes again.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue?lq=1) but nothing helps.

Comment: can you please provide logcat error here?

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would be getting the Facebook Error when you try to login.
You have to solve this yourself! :(…but yeah first find out what the problem is. Try to log the error (in the `onFacebookError` method, add a log entry and log the error details) and then you should be able to see the description of what exactly is going wrong; that should be a good start.