# Application is misconfigured for Facebook Integration

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App is misconfigured for Facebook login : Android Facebook integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)

Getting strange problem from Facebook SDK
`Application is Mis-Configured for Facebook login.
Press Okay to go back to the application without connecting to Facebook.`

Question already asked [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue), I tried but not finding any solution in given answers.

this problem does not return any error or response or any exception..
already changed more then 2 to 3 APP_IDs..

[image]

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried checking logcat to see what kind of error message is displayed after pressing the "Okay" button?  You mentioned you have already set your own APP_ID, but did you put your Android Hash Key in your [dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)?

If you still can't get it to work, follow the steps [here in our documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/) to see if you can set it up and authenticate with our sample app.  The sample app is **guaranteed** to work if you have implemented it correctly - if you can't set up Hackbook to work correctly, then you can't set up your own app correctly.  If you are able to get Hackbook working, then you just need to make sure you're doing the same thing in your app to work.

Comment: Whether Android Hash Key is necessary...??? @Jesse Chen

Comment: in emulator it is working fine but in device showing this error...

Comment: I had tried on different devices which has default Facebook app, on that devices my app is not working. if i uninstall Facebook default app my application is perfectly running and sharing the data....

Comment: Android Hash Key is required in your app dashboard if you want login to work with the Facebook app installed.  Read this to see how to put your hash key in.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig

Comment: done thanks.... prob of Android Hash Key only...

Comment: @JesseChen sir, i have included hash key but still it is showing the same error on Nexus 7 but running perfectly on Samsung galaxy 7" tab.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple...

Just change the function in facebook.java :-

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        final DialogListener listener) {
    authorize(activity, permissions, **DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE**, listener);
}
```

to-----
    public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            final DialogListener listener) {
        authorize(activity, permissions, **FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH**, listener);
    }
it will work..

Answer (score 2):

I have toiled for two days & got the solution at last, this is the **WRONG** way to get the hash key -

```
keytool -exportcert -alias *<your _alias_name>* -keystore *<key_store_path>* | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl sha1 -binary | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl base64
```

The **RIGHT** way is described here -

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13281913/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-with-release-key-hash

or here

[Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)