# App is misconfigured for Facebook login IOS Facebook app installed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

I saw this link[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)
But it doesn't solve my problem.

I downloaded the latest Facebook sdk 3.1.1
The original SessionLoginSample provided with sdk works fine.
I made the following changes and the result is: **App is misconfigured for Facebook login**
Where is my mistake?

---

I created a new sample Facebook app following step by step the Facebook doc:
[Facebook App Image on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/giuseppeandreamosca/8069815404/in/photostream)

I loaded in xCode the original SessionLoginSample and I changed only the bundleId and the Facebook ID:
[xCode plist image on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/giuseppeandreamosca/8069794496/in/photostream)

Comment: please recheck the enter link description you have mention in you you r question, i add a answer there its causes due to not setting the right bundle identifier...hope it will help you !

Answer (score 2):

i experienced the same problem many times.
First make sure you have your Facebookappid set in your property list correctly.
Then go to facebook account settings  and delete your ios app from applications.
then go to developer settings of facebook for your ios app.Make sure the app id is correct and also make sure that the bundle identifier is also same as your propertylist in xcode.It should be working afterwards

**UPDATED :** You do not need to delete the app.Try delete the app from your Facebook settings first.Then go to your Facebook app on iOS and log out.Remove your own app from the device and reinstall (without loving in to your account).Then you try to connect from your own app Facebook will prompt and ak your username and password and it will not return to your app.You clsoe the app and return to your own app manually.When you try to connect again in your own app FB it will ask you for permissions.
I reproduced the problem somehow and fixed like this.

By the way i also set the App Type: setting in advanded settings to Native/Dssktop.

Comment: You can follow the links to flickr photos inside the post and you can see that all is good. I checked several times what you said, deleted and recreated app on Facebook. No solved

Comment: Update: I deleted Facebook app, authorized my iphone app by Safari, worked fine. I reinstalled Facebook APP on iPhone, SessionLoginSample worked fine. From my facebook page I removed SessionLoginSample app. I tried again to authorize my SessionLoginSample, Misconfigured error.

Comment: if the app is redirected to facebook homepage login proces is not SSO.Thats why it works in safari and does not over facebook app.Are you sure about your configurations in app settings?

Comment: I followed the documetation step by step, I'm sure there must be something wrong in facebook configuration but what Have I to check? I'm looking for it, because the original SessionLoginSample works fine but I can't see the configuration of facebook team about that app in facebook developers page (app is a too common word here).

Comment: as you can see comment was left on 11 October 2012 which was also long time ago i think you placed the comment to to wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured your app properly as per the following guidelines https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ Check whether you bundle id is as per you configured in the Native ios settings of app configuration.

Comment: UPDATE: the configuration was good, no errors, for unknown reasons I had to wait about some hours, after that all worked fine