# app is misconfigured for facebook login

Tags: android

I am having a lot of trouble with this error:

> app is misconfigured to facebook login

I am pretty new to android development and would appreciate any answers I can find.
I have seen many of the same errors here so I followed as best as I could but I still have something wrong. I have checked the hash keys and they seem alright.

My app works when I use the eclipse and my phone, but it does not work when I install from google play.

I have opened `Util.java` in the Facebook SDK, set `private static boolean ENABLE_LOG=true`.

I changed the hash key in my facebook console and got the error that the key don't match.
I put the original back and no longer get that error but the app is still misconfigured in Facebook login.

I am sure there is something else wrong on the console but I have no idea what it is or how to fix it.  I have been at this for three days now.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you posts some code so we can see what you have tried already?

Comment: you should also tell us what is happening, not just that there is an error.

Comment: brenjt - what code do you want to see?  wouldn't you want to see the console?  forgive me... i am very new

Comment: toadzky - I am trying to run my app.  I download it from google play.  It gives me the error "app misconfigured for facebook login".  I try to run it from my console in eclipse and everything is fine.

Comment: this was in google play and working fine.  Facebook added a new error message and it caught something that I didn't do right on the console.  I thought it was the hash key but it was not.

Comment: I also am getting this error in the console.                        App Detail Page Status: Live
Your app detail page is now live and will appear in Search.
App Center Listing Status: Unlisted
Your app is not listed because it does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be listed in the App Center at this time. Please refer to your app's Insights page to view your app's user rating and engagement metrics, and view our App Center guidelines for more information.
Web Preview Mobile Preview  Cancel Submission

Comment: I also have the Facebook App installed.

Comment: @brenjt - i forgot the @ sign.

Comment: @toadzky - i forgot the @ sign

Comment: Hi I found that the both the debug and release hash keys had to be added to the facebook developer console. Facebook has a brand new error message that really helps.  When the hash key is wrong, there is a message saying what that hash key is!!!!!!!! copy paste into facebook developer console!!!!! YEAH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found that the both the debug and release hash keys had to be added to the facebook developer console. Facebook has a brand new error message that really helps. When the hash key is wrong, there is a message saying what that hash key is!!!!!!!! copy paste into facebook developer console!!!!! YEAH

Answer (score 0):

I think you follow all steps to create your hash key with your command prompt. I also face this issue.

I got a hash key which is different than my LogCat key. For that just connect your device and check your error with LogCat. This throws a Facebook exception like

> D/Facebook-authorize(24739): Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "uk3udeH7vrOGNFH2FJjdJbdWJWI" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers

This `uk3udeH7vrOGNFH2FJjdJbdWJWI` is a sample key. Get your key from your LogCat  and change hash key on Facebook apps.

See the accepted answer here:
[App is misconfigured for Facebook login: Android Facebook integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)