# SessionState is CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED in FB native login

Tags: android, facebook-login

i want to use Facebook Native login

i am following http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/   . i get the permissions alert box but when i select `ok` i get the SessionState as CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED .

i rechecked the App keyHash also . Is there any method to get the KeyHash from the code itself , i mean to print the keyhash with which it checks while comparing .

i went through many other threads too but was not successful , i dont know where i am going wrong . what are all the possibilities , so that i may recieve this error . Any related answers are welcomed .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of generating the keyhash thorough command line use the following code to get the key hash. 
Some other things you need to take care of is 
1)setting a proper package name in the facebook settings 
2) enabling facebook login on facebook app settings dashboard

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.example.com.tvishi.fb", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: After several attempts it worked. Similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486377/android-facebook-api-exception-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and tried all the solutions mentioned above, none of which resolved the issue.  In my case, I kept getting this error on my test device phone (htc my touch).  I noticed that when I tried logging into facebook with my browser on the phone, it kept giving me certificate errors!  So I finally figured out that the date and time on my phone was not correct. After fixing that, the CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED error went away. Hope that helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

You have to listed all keyhash you have there. If your key hash is not listed there, then you wont be able to login, FB will reject you.

If you move to another computer, again, you need to do it again.