# Fb login error status closed login failed

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing problem in Facebook login in android,i have create key hash using method that facebook provide and added it to facebook developers console.
I have updated my manifest-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <meta-data 
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
     android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
               android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

and below is my code in activity -

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    else{
        if(isFbClick){
            Session s = new Session(mContext);
            Session.setActiveSession(s);
            s.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email")));
        }
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    flag = true;
    if(session.isClosed()){
        state  = SessionState.CLOSED;
    }
    if (session.isOpened() && state.isOpened()) {
            accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
            accessExpir = session.getExpirationDate();
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                if(mDialog==null){
                    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                }
                if(!mDialog.isShowing()){
                    mDialog.setMessage("please wait...");
                    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    mDialog.show();
                }
                 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                     public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          session.close();
                          session.removeCallback(callback);
                          getUserFacebookData(user);
                     }
                 });
             }
    }else if(state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)){

    }
    else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}


 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     if(session.isOpened()){
         session.close();
         session = null;
     }
}
```

and code inside my oncreate is -

```
     uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
     uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
        authButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb_login);
        authButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0,0);
        authButton.setText("");
        authButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isFbClick = true;
                Session s = new Session(mContext);
                Session.setActiveSession(s);
                s.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) mContext).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email")));
            }
        });
```

at the end when i click facebook button it returns error after user login -
Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.
I have try it on both Mobile(with facebook app installed and not installed) and emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the keyHash on developers.facebook.com for your application?

Check it out. There is a way how to obtain your keyHash.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15287332/3025055

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have all ready used this code to generate key hash and also try using command prompt both generate same key hash but while login through facebook it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem but it is a common problem (it was for me when I implemented Facebook). Chances are you have the wrong hash key. Put this in your onCreate method:

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "com.example.com.tvishi.fb", 
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

This will Log the hashkey that Facebook is trying to use. If you copy that hashkey into your Facebook developer's console, it may solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have all ready used this code to generate key hash and also try using command prompt both generate same key hash but while login through facebook it gives error.

Comment: no, it doent gives any error.When user click facebook button then after few delay onActivity result called and then onSessionState shoe Login Failed session closed status.