# Facebook login exception from mobile

Tags: java, android, facebook

When I connect try to connect to `Facebook`.

I click on the facebook login Button from the android emulator It's show me the Facebook's login page as usual and everything is ok.

However, when I try to run it on my `Galaxy S2` It shows me an exception in the logcat (a week ago everything was working well without any exception- I was able to connect to `Facebook` from mobile and Android emulator too)

Today, I can only login with the android emulator, I don't know what I can't connect from my Android device.

Here is the logcat:

```
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id 
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:208)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:266)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:27)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:141)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:284)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:185)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:248)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:49)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:193)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at com.facebook.common.util.HandlerExecutorServiceImpl$ListenableScheduledFuture.run(HandlerExecutorServiceImpl.java:268)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 00:31:52.750: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:OrcaServiceQueue(9725):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725): Failed to send
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725): com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:616)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:41)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation$2.run(OrcaServiceOperation.java:581)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-03 00:31:52.785: W/fb4a(:<default>):fb:GDPDialog(9725):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you changed the app signature or made it a release version ? Refer to this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894006/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-gives-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id-while-lo)

Comment: according to logcat the app id you store in your project doesn't match with the one you store on your Facebook account. Make sure they are same.

Comment: hi, i found the problem, when i installed the oficial facebook app from market, my app doesnt successes to connect to facebook, however when i un-install the official facebook app, when i click on the login facebook button it shows me the connection screen of facebook as usual..what is the problem with the official facebook app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Official App (Market Version) to the facebook dashboard and then use the same API KEY they provide you to connect, otherwise the versions won't work.

You can create a dev/staging version of your app in facebook too, and use that while your app is being developed, but the SDK is telling you that the API key you're supplying the FB SDK with, doesn't match with that they have on the website for your App's signature.