# Facebook session won't stay active

Tags: java, android, facebook, api

So i'm writing a simple authentication method, but what happens is the session doesn't get opened at all...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class FBAuth extends Activity {

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbauth);

            Log.v("AUTH","SESSION STARTING");

            // start FB Login
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        Log.v("AUTH","SESSION ACTIVE");

                      // make request to the /me API
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Log.v("AUTH:","USERNAME: " + user.getFirstName());
                                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    else if (state.isClosed()) {
                        Log.v("AUTH", "SESSION CLOSED");
                    }
                }    
            });

        }


      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

}
```

Logcat:

```
10-16 15:58:21.104: V/AUTH(26525): SESSION STARTING 
10-16 15:58:23.797: V/AUTH(26525): SESSION CLOSED
```

Logcat for the facebook process:

```
10-16 16:01:49.598: I/ActivityManager(430): START u0 {act=SSO_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=com.mumin.facebookconnect/com.facebook.LoginActivity (has extras)} from pid 26525
10-16 16:01:49.818: I/ActivityManager(430): Displayed com.mumin.facebookconnect/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +222ms (total +290ms)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash ********************** does not match any stored key hashes.
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:162)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:285)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:272)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:29)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:160)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:366)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:259)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:296)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
10-16 16:01:50.278: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
10-16 16:01:50.308: I/ActivityManager(430): START u0 {act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_ACTIVITY cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformActivity (has extras)} from pid 26525
10-16 16:01:50.359: I/ActivityManager(430): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformWrapperActivity (has extras)} from pid 25219
10-16 16:01:50.849: I/ActivityManager(430): Displayed com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformActivity: +510ms
10-16 16:01:50.869: I/ActivityManager(430): Displayed com.facebook.katana/.platform.PlatformWrapperActivity: +500ms
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash 1gcqjsUopNOpDvlaJ6a43CIaakA does not match any stored key hashes.
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:162)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:285)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:272)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:29)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:160)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:366)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:259)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:296)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
10-16 16:01:52.471: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25219):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
10-16 16:01:52.511: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(25219): com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
10-16 16:01:52.511: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(25219):    at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:637)
10-16 16:01:52.511: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(25219):    at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:45)
10-16 16:01:52.511: W/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(25219):    at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation$2.run(BlueServiceOperation.java:602)
```

I thought perhaps the authentication was failing due to a bad key hash, so i generated a new one to no avail.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894006/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-gives-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id-while-lo

Comment: Maybe it's cuz a bad key hash, but why don't you try an easier approach? like use the `UiLifecycleHelper` with the `LoginButton`?

Comment: Since the error now tells you the exact key hash that's not matching, why not put "1gcqjsUopNOpDvlaJ6a43CIaakA" into your app settings?

Comment: Just a note to people Googling the Facebook error 'Key hash ** does not match any stored key hashes', the error log gives you the hash to paste into your Facebook developer console. But for some reason, the Logcat output replaces + with - and / with _. So change these characters back and add into your FB dev console, it should work.