# using facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am developing an android app which is intended to use Facebook login.Users will log into the app using their Facebook credentials.All is working fine when the Facebook for android app is not installed.However,when the device has the Facebook for android app installed,the app doesn't get beyond the login interface.How can i rectify that?Any assistance will be highly appreciated.Thanks.
Below is the code for the login activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.facebook.Session;


public class MokoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    TextView create_account;
    EditText name;
    //private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private boolean isResumed=false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        create_account=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_createAccount);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        create_account.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.textView_createAccount:
                String user_name=name.getText().toString();
                if(user_name.length()<4){
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MokoActivity.this,"Invalid Name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else{
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true,new Session.StatusCallback(){
                public void call(Session session,SessionState state,Exception exception){
                    if(state.isOpened()){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MokoActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username",name.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onResume(){
        Session session=Session.getActiveSession();
        if(session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())){
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        super.onResume();
         isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if(isResumed){
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MokoActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username",name.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MokoActivity.this,"Logged out...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
          }
        }
    }
    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue this issue?

Comment: @RobinHood nope.the app works fine when Facebook for android is not installed on the device

Comment: open Facebook class and change the package default to your. at line `484`

Comment: Do any of the sample apps that ship with the SDK work with the FB app installed? What version of the Facebook app do you have? Did you put the LoginActivity into your AndroidManifest?

Comment: @MingLi none is working.As for the LoginActivity,no the manifest will only include your self made activities.You can visit the facebook developer site for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FACEBOOK SDK LIBRARY PROJECT . 
in **FACEBOOK.JAVA** line nos from 181 to 199 replace with the following codes.

```
**public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {
       // boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;
        mAuthDialogListener = listener;
      /*  // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
        if (activityCode >= 0) {
            singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                    permissions, activityCode);
        }
        // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
        if (!singleSignOnStarted) {
            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
        }*/

        startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }**
```

it will work perfectly only in api wont get link with facebook app which installed in mobile.

Comment: in my sdk in the said file,it is completely different.In lines 181-199 its just comments.May be in line 290.

Comment: oh.. so check for those methods and lines.

Comment: from where you have downloaded the sdk ?

Comment: The method is implemented differently.And i downloaded it from the Facebook developers site.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66668531/android.rar use this url to download older version .. it will work well..

Comment: do u mind posting the link to the complete sdk?changing part of the files brings about multiple issues/errors.Thanks.

Comment: above link alone is enough to do the facebook login .. i am using that sdk only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to install application , then you have to check your package name  , Check the exception if your exception is bad Character exception like '_' or unable to parse package name  . then please Do change your package name . It must not contain character like _(underscore) . and also change the same in AndroidManifest.xml .