# Facebook error "login misconfigured"

Tags: android, facebook-social-plugins

error in my Logcat is:

02-12 10:04:54.240: E/SurfaceFlinger(521): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
02-12 10:04:54.250: D/libEGL(521): egl.cfg not found, using default config
02-12 10:04:54.260: D/libEGL(521): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_bst.so
02-12 10:04:54.260: W/PGA(521): eglGetProcAddress: "eglGetRenderBufferANDROID" not found
02-12 10:04:55.260: E/HdIpc(521): Connect failed err = -1 errno = 110 (ETIMEDOUT). Timeout log will be logged only once per process
02-12 10:04:55.260: E/PGA(521): Failed to connect to host, err = -1, retrying... This will be logged only once per process to avoid flooding the logs.

when my phone show that error and when i press ok button which is on the fb page right top corner. I have also generate hash key and put it into dash board. it is working well when i uninstall fb app from my mob. but doen't work with fb app. please help me

Comment: There's an easier way, check out this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22568861/570612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At times, the key hash that you have generated isn't quite the right one. *Apparently* (unconfirmed of course), it has something to do with JRE 1.7.

Follow one of the two solutions below, and you should be good to go.

**Solution 1:**

Try this link: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1. I found that using the Facebook method of getting a Hash Key did not always work as advertised. This link however, has a different method of getting the Hash Key and has pretty much always worked.

**Solution 2:**

That being said, I always found the simplest thing to do was, *let the Facebook SDK tell you what your Hash Key is*. This is by far more simpler and shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

Step 1:
In your Facebook SDK, locate the *Util.java* class. In that, change this:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;
```

to:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;
```

Step 2:
Create a **new** Signed APK, transfer to your device and install. If it is already installed, naturally, it will prompt.

Step 3: With your DDMS (Logcat) running and your device connected to the computer, run the application and keep looking for a *key mismatch* warning. That warning has the **actual** Hash Key. Copy that key, go to your Facebook Developer page and add the new key to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with keystore hash key. You can install [openSSL](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/source/checkout) (Download appropriate for your system i.e 32 bit/64 bit this is important) and using following commands generate hash key. This will solved the problem.

```
 @echo Exporting keystore cert
keytool -exportcert -alias myalias -keystore mycert.keystore > mycert.keystore.bin

@echo Converting to sha1
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary mycert.keystore.bin > mycert.keystore.sha1

@echo Converting to base64
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64 -in mycert.keystore.sha1 -out mycert.keystore.base64

@echo Done, Android hash key for Facebook app is:
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64 -in mycert.keystore.sha1
```