# facebook error misconfigured

Tags: android, facebook

> Step 2: Create a new Signed APK, transfer to your device and install. If it is already installed, naturally, it will prompt.
>
> Step 3: With your DDMS (Logcat) running and your device connected to the computer, run the application and keep looking for a key mismatch warning. That warning has the actual Hash Key. Copy that key, go to your Facebook Developer page and add the new key to the list.

I have already hash key in my FB dashboard.

I try these steps but I haven't get any key in log cat it's simple key mismatch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue

Answer (score 0):

have you read the tutorial on the Facebook developers website?

you need to sign your app. the way to do this is to run this on Linux/Mac

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

or this on Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

as shown on the [Getting Started manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)