# Misconfig for Facebook login android

Tags: android, facebook, fbconnect

Just trying to implement facebook integration with my android app but it shows me Misconfig for facebook login, I am sure of my hashkeys I generated it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app) and my facebook app config is [like this](http://s24.postimage.org/kuvor5j1x/Capture1.png)

and it still gives me that error :S

Edit: my code

```
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with
                                // user object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {


                                        userPassword = user.getId();
                                        String email = user.getLink();
                                        email = email.replace(".", "");
                                        email = email
                                                .replace("http://", "");
                                        email = email.replace("https://",
                                                "");
                                        email = email.replace("/", "");
                                        email = email + "@anydomains.com";

                                        userMail = email;
                                        new Login(true).execute();

                                        // register with fb


                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: post you code for detail

Comment: or read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn I edited it and added my code

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn I tried the webview or the hackbook and it doesn't work also :S

Comment: check out my answer, I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you could try this:

Try to debug your app, in **onSessionstateChange** see for **Exception** not null. If your signature does not match, you will receive right signature of your app in Exception (also you could see it in logcat), than past it to FaceBook dev console.

**UPDATE**:

Following code works for me:

```
@Override
protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) 
{
    if (exception != null)
    {   
        Log.i(TAG, exception.toString());
    }
    if (state.isOpened()) 
    {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest( this.getSession(),
                                    new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
            {

            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
}
```

If your keyhash does not match, you will see it here in **LogCat**

```
if (exception != null)
{   
    Log.i(TAG, exception.toString());
}
```